# Is it always a good practice to wrap a recursive function?

Tags: java, function, recursion, wrapper

I am using a recursive function to calculate the number of possible traversals through a graph starting from a node and ends with another given a set of rules (eg: minimum/maximum/exact number of stops).

I am wondering if it is a good practice to call a wrapper function that calls the recursive function instead of calling it directly. Most of the time I see people use a wrapper function.

Just wondering why and what are the pros and cons and in what situations must we wrap it?

Comment: You don't have to provide a "wrapper" method but in many cases the recursive methods need some setup for the recursion that the caller shouldn't have to worry about so the "wrapper" method provides an easy entry point. As an example one could take a recursive quicksort method that might have the signature `sort(left, right)`. Since most of the time you'd just want to sort everything, the entry point would be the "wrapper" method `sort()` which internally starts the recursion via `sort(0, size-1)`.

Comment: AFAIK, the wrapper is typically used to diminish parameters of the "actual" recursive method. If the no. of parameters are less (as to less meaning ymmv), the method directly can be used. Nice question +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not always necessary. You only need to wrap it when you have a specific reason to. Here are a couple of reasons you might need to wrap it:

- If the arguments it passes to itself are different from the arguments it receives in the initial call, for whatever reason

  - Perhaps the recursion arguments are complex and it would be difficult for the caller to supply appropriate initial values for them
  - Perhaps the initial arguments are markedly different from the recursive ones
- If you need the starting position (e.g., the wrapper) to have a different access level than the recursive method itself.

There are probably several more.

But lots of recursive methods don't need wrapping. For instance, the classic depth-first node traversal method with a predicate doesn't need anything special passed during recursion vs. during the initial call, so there's no need to wrap it.

Answer (score 0):

a recursive function usually require an argument that represents cumulative result from previous call. a hypothetical example from the problem domain would be

```
public int numberOfPossibleTraversals(Node node, List<Rule> rules) { ...
```

so the first arg is modified in each recursive call. You start the chain of calls with a starter value like this

```
int c = numberOfPossibleTraversals(root, rules);
```

sometimes (depending on the specific implementation) establishing starter values for the cumulative args may require some logic/processing. that is where "wrapper" methods may come into play. for example, the graph itself may have such a wrapper function that builds the args for the recursive function