# Why do we use a wrapper function for a recursive function?

Tags: c++, function, recursion, wrapper

What is the purpose of a wrapper over recursive function? 
Why can't we directly call the recursive function from the main function?
I've come across some explanations saying that wrapper function helps in better parameter passing - I don't understand this.

EDIT:
Consider the example of a binary search based function that returns the index of a peak element:

```
int findPeakUtil(int arr[], int low,  
                 int high, int n)  
{  
    // Find index of middle element  
    int mid = low + (high - low)/2; 



   // Compare middle element with its neighbours (if neighbours exist)  
    if ((mid == 0 || arr[mid - 1] <= arr[mid]) &&  
        (mid == n - 1 || arr[mid + 1] <= arr[mid]))  
        return mid;  

    // If middle element is not peak and its  
    // left neighbour is greater than it, 
    // then left half must have a peak element  
    else if (mid > 0 && arr[mid - 1] > arr[mid])  
        return findPeakUtil(arr, low, (mid - 1), n);  

    // If middle element is not peak and its  
    // right neighbour is greater than it,  
    // then right half must have a peak element  
    else return findPeakUtil(arr, (mid + 1), high, n);  
}  

// A wrapper over recursive function findPeakUtil()  
int findPeak(int arr[], int n)  
{  
    return findPeakUtil(arr, 0, n - 1, n);  
}
```

Why is it recommended to use the wrapper function?

Comment: Could you add an example?

Comment: Sometimes a wrapper is used for simplicity, like removing negatives or anything, so that less checks have to be done in the recursive function itself. It depends on the context. If you provide an example, someone could probably explain its purpose.

Comment: Some reasons [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Wrapper_function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57690195/5987698).

Comment: who is "we" and why do you think you cannot call a recursive function directly?

Answer (score 1):

A wrapper function can prepare a call of a recursive function. For example a recursive function has more parameters then initially the user supplies. Or can make a preliminary checks of the validity of arguments and tests pre-conditions.

Here is a simple example provided for the demonstrative purpose.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

char * recursive_reverse( char *s, size_t n )
{
    if ( n < 2 ) return s;

    char c = s[0];
    s[0] = s[n-1];
    s[n-1] = c;

    recursive_reverse( s + 1, n - 2 );

    return s;
}

char * reverse( char *s )
{
    return recursive_reverse( s, std::strlen( s ) );
}

int main() 
{
    char s[] = "Hello DEBNATH KUNDU";

    std::cout << s << '\n';
    std::cout << reverse( s ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello DEBNATH KUNDU
UDNUK HTANBED olleH
```

Another example is when a class has a non-static public member function that calls a static (private/protected) recursive member function passing to it required data members of the object of the class. So in this case the non-static member function provides the public interface and the non-static recursive function provides the implementation of the interface.

Here is one more demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <cstring>

class String
{
private:
    enum Size : size_t { N = 100 };
    char s[N];

    static void recursive_reverse( char *s, size_t n )
    {
        if ( not ( n < 2 ) )
        {
            std::swap( s[0], s[n-1] );
            recursive_reverse( s + 1, n - 2 );
        }
    }       

public:
    explicit String( const char *s )
    {
        strncpy( this->s, s, N );
        this->s[N-1] = '\0';
    }

    void reverse() { recursive_reverse( s, std::strlen( s ) ); }

    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const String &s )
    {
        return os << s.s;
    }
};


int main() 
{
    String s(  "Hello DEBNATH KUNDU" );

    std::cout << s << '\n';

    s.reverse();

    std::cout << s << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is the same as shown above.

However it does not mean that a wrapper function is always required.